# Поиск опечаток методом сравнения двух списков фраз

Tags: delphi, строки, нечеткий-поиск

Есть 2 базы. в одной идеальное написание слов, в другой импорт из других баз.
Там бывают ошибки аля (Spirit of Maya вместо Spirits of Maya, Pharaon вместо Pharaohn) Записей очень много. глазами не пробежаться, начинают в кучу собираться.

Как можно найти отличие в 1-3 символа пробегаясь в цикле ?

```
for i := 0 to Length(IdealArray) - 1 do
begin
  for x := 0 to Length(SomeMissArray) - 1 do
  begin
    Тут по идее производится проверка всего. но вот как её реализовать не могу родить
  end;
end;
```

Comment: недавно что-то обсуждали тут про `soundex` для русского. Не пойдет для поиска схожих фраз. А потом эти схожие уже проверять?

Comment: Пробовал. Мне кажется легче уже смириться. Слишком много подводных камней получается как-то. Самое адекватное решение , которое придумал - это через регулярные сделать. Через Copy() и Pos() фигарим до первой буквы которая не такая, потом заносим в переменную все правильные буквы. и через регулярное : "наша переменная+(.*?)+следующаябуква" если нашлось - значит опечатка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для поиска опечаток существуют [алгоритмы нечёткого поиска](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/).
Один из них [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) с реализацией [на Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - это искать расстояние от позиции каждой буквы слова до позиции такой же буквы другого слова. Для одинаковых слов сумма расстояний будет равна нулю. Для слов с опечаткой сумма будет мала, а для не похожих велика.
Для слов с разной длинной, нужно сравнивать длинное слово с коротким.
Возможно, мой алгоритм не верный - придумал его за минуту.

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, если буквы нет, то за расстояние стоит брать расстояние до ближайшего края второго слова. Так мне кажется.

Comment: сейчас попробую нечто подобное

Comment: Не в баню. не получается и всё.  =)